# Force Brave Browser to use system DNS on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, dns, browser, brave

I have the following problem:

In my network exists a DNS server *(network-pi; 192.168.28.77)* which can resolve locally hosted pages in addition to the normal name resolution for the "Internet". On my operating system *(Linux Mint 21.1)* in `/etc/resolv.conf` there is the following entry: `nameserver 192.168.28.77`

`dig google.com` gives me the following output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17647
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  A   142.251.36.238

;; Query time: 84 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.28.77#53(192.168.28.77) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 06 09:55:53 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

As can be seen, the local DNS server *(192.168.28.77)* is used.

`dig network-pi` (so resolving the DNS'es own domain) also prints the correct IP of the DNS server.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> network-pi
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13511
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;network-pi.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
network-pi.     0   IN  A   192.168.28.77

;; Query time: 36 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.28.77#53(192.168.28.77) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 06 09:58:14 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

also, ping can resolve local names.

```
PING network-pi (192.168.28.77) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pi.hole (192.168.28.77): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=65.0 ms
64 bytes from pi.hole (192.168.28.77): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=35.1 ms
64 bytes from pi.hole (192.168.28.77): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=36.4 ms
64 bytes from pi.hole (192.168.28.77): icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=35.4 ms
^C64 bytes from 192.168.28.77: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=36.5 ms

--- network-pi ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.095/41.690/64.982/11.659 ms
```

However, when I enter the URL *"http://network-pi"* in the Brave browser *(version 1.49.132 Chromium: 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit))*, I get an error message that Brave could not find the URL. I learned on the Internet that Brave uses an external resolver for secure DNS. For this reason, I have deactivated *"brave://settings/security -> Use secure DNS"*. However, I still can't reach local domains via Brave Browser.

In Firefox, everything works fine

So how can I force the Brave browser to use a local DNS server?

Thanks for your help.